# How to preserve the URL / avoid page refresh when using Angular $resource.get or .query?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in my template:

```
<button value="Test Service (Search)" ng-click="$ctrl.SearchForPersonByName('winn', false)">
    Test Service (Search)</button>
```

In the controller I have:

```
self.SearchForPersonByName = function (searchTerm, onlyPractitioners)
{
    var searchResource = $resource('../angularSupport/controllers/common/PersonNameSearch/');

    var params = new Object();
    params.searchTerm = searchTerm;
    params.onlyPractitioners = onlyPractitioners;

    // saw this on StackOverflow but this doesn't stop it from refreshing the page
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    var dataResult = searchResource.query(params);
    dataResult.$promise.then(function (data)
    {
        // this never executes; page refreshes instead

        self.data = data; // update model data
        console.log('Data: ' + data); // check data format

        UpdateAutoComplete(); // will show a dropdown list of names to pick from,
        // given the search text and result, using self.data
    });

    console.log('path: ' + $location.path());
}
```

The path log:

```
path: /ha/1338378
```

The full path is:

```
/WebContent/Pages/MyPage.aspx#!/ha/1338378
```

After a $resource performs a query or get, the result is navigation to:

```
/WebContent/Pages/MyPage.aspx
```

Instead of navigation I only want to get data from the server and use it to update the name list. I want to keep the same URL.

When tracing, the window unload event occurs without the callback ever getting called. Angular is getting a response from the XHR request that appears well-formed so it's not a server issue.

Answer (score -1):

`$resource` service has nothing to do with page refreshing. The problem may exists in your server side code